# can't able to get HashMap position in CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I made Custom adapter for HashMap, the problem is i unable to set TextView of CustomAdapter with HashMap. The **second last line getting syntax** error to getting HashMap position. 
Kindly guide me how to resolve syntax error and set CustomAdapter.

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, Object>> {

        private SparseBooleanArray mSelectedItemsIds;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context mContext;
        private List<HashMap<String, Object>> list;
        Blocklist blocklist;

        public CustomAdapter (Context context, int resourceId, List<HashMap<String, Object>> list) {
            super(context, resourceId, list);
            mSelectedItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
            mContext = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            this.list = list;
        }

        private static class ViewHolder {
            TextView itemName;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if (view == null) {
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_textview, null);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_textview, null);
                holder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.custom_tv);
                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

            holder.itemName.setText(list.get(position));
            return view;
        }
```

Blocklist.java

```
HashMap<String,Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                hm.put(ID, cursor.getLong(0));
                hm.put(ORIGINATING_ADDRESS, cursor.getString(1));
                hm.put(MESSAGE_BODY, cursor.getString(2));
                arrayList.add(hm);
                cursor.moveToNext();
```

Comment: add the error log.

Comment: Why 2 times inflater in getView.

Comment: mistakenly enter @jaydroider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have :

```
holder.itemName.setText(list.get(position));
```

the above line will not work as `list.get(position)` results in a Hashmap object and not a string object. If you want fro example to show the MESSAGE_BODY you must use it like this

```
 holder.itemName.setText((String)list.get(position).get(MESSAGE_BODY));
```

also you do not need to inflate

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_textview, null);
```

twice`

Answer (score 0):

```
list.get(position)
```

Return the object `HashMap` in `position`, not a `String`